# Django makemigrations Issue

Tags: python, django, makemigrations

I am stumped. I have a custom model field class that looks for two arguments: app_name and file_dir.

In my model definition I have this:

```
files = MultiFileUploadAndViewer(app_name = getAppName(), file_dir='RequestedFiles', blank=True)
```

getAppName() is:

```
#appconfig imported from apps.py 
def getAppName():
    return <appConfig>.name
```

And the custom field definition is:

```
class MultiFileUploadAndViewer(models.FilePathField):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs['app_name'])
    self.app_name = kwargs.pop('app_name')
    self.file_dir = kwargs.pop('file_dir','') + '\\'
    self.path = MEDIA_ROOT + '\\' + self.app_name + '\\' + self.file_dir
    self.upload_url = reverse(self.app_name +':File Upload') + '\\' + self.file_dir
    kwargs.update({'path':self.path})
    super(MultiFileUploadAndViewer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I deleted everything in the migrations folder except for **init**.py.

Upon running makemigrations, it throws a KeyError complaining that 'app_name' is not in kwargs.

However, notice the call to print() in the fields **init** method. That successfully prints the app_name. The KeyError comes after. Is the **init** function being called twice or something? Thus throwing the error after 'app_name
 gets popped off of kwargs? How can I address this issue? If I provide a default for app_name in the pop() method, this works, but I want it to error out if app_name (or file_dir) are not present in kwargs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The init method is called again by the super class models.FilePathField here:

```
super(MultiFileUploadAndViewer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And you are deleting the kwargs app_name here

```
self.app_name = kwargs.pop('app_name')
```

Comment: Wow I had a fundamental misunderstanding of what was going on. I thought that the super call would run the superclass' __init__?

Comment: Yes, it is doing, but without app_name and file_dir keyword arguments because you are poping them out

Comment: I am confused as to why FilePathField (the superclass) is calling MultiFileUploadAndViewer (my custom subclass) __init__. If I do not pop the kwargs, FilePathField complains about receiveing unexpected kwargs.

Comment: The superclass is not calling the subclass, cannot you add a import pdb; pdb.set_trace() and debug after popping?